# IBM xSeries 335 General Questions (power usage and installation)

Tags: installation, ibm, electrical-power, ibm-xseries, remote-access

I just received a 2nd hand IBM xSeries 335 1U rack mountable server, and I have a few questions about it:

1. How do I install it? Is there an Installation Utility disk like for the HP Proliant servers (SmartStart do they call it if I remember correctly)? If yes, how is it called, and where do I get it?
2. What are the power requirements - how much Ampère do I need for it: 0.5A, or 1.0A, or more? Below are the specs... (I need this to know how much a place in a datacenter will cost)
3. Is there a device like the iLO on HP servers on such IBM servers?

These are the specs:

- 2x 36.4 SCSI 10k RPM HDD.
- 2x 2.4 Ghz Intel XEON processor
- 2GB RAM (2 modules of 1GB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [IBM Support Site](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Overview) is quite extensive and useful.  You should visit and check for other associated updates for your model hardware.

1. IBM provides deployment software called [ServerGuide](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=SERV-GUIDE&brandind=5000008).
2. IBM provides [documentation](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/Documentation/Hardware/Systems/System_x/xSeries_335) indicating the following power specs:

   - 100 to 127 (nominal) V ac; 50 Hz or 60 Hz; 4 A
   - 200 to 240 (nominal) V ac; 50 Hz or 60 Hz; 2 A
   - Input kilovolt-amperes (kVA) (approximately):
   - Minimum configuration: 0.120 kVA
   - Maximum configuration: 0.400 kVA
3. IBM uses what's called a Remote Supervisor Adapter (RSA). The RSA is an add-in card, you would have to verify if it is installed or not. It looks like the below picture.
   [image: RSA Card]

Comment: Thanks. I tried to search on the IBM site, but for me, it's too chaotic to find something on it...